# Object with volume absorption, in an environment with volume absorption

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I have tried different approaches, some of which work, but feel more like workarounds than proper solutions.

Let's say:

1. I have an environment (in the most simple case, the world, alternatively an object like a cube), featuring volume absorption
2. I place a transparent object (e.g. a cube) inside that environment.
3. The object has a different volume absorption (in the most simple case: none) than the environment.

If I press render, then ASFAIKS the volume absorption of the environment is effective everywhere, i.e. also inside the object.

However, there are situations in nature, where this not the case. E.g. if we imagine a drop of clear oil in muddy water.

So, my question is: What is the most elegant way to model this?

Booling out the object from the environment is the best solution I have so far, however it gets a little cumbersome if the object itself is also supposed to have volume absorption, since I have to work around intersecting geometry, etc. So I thought that there could be a more elegant way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would a boolean modifier chop out a portion of the inside of the larger volume?

Comment: Exactly. If I wanted the object to have no absorption at all, that would be fine, But if I want the object itself to have volume absorption as well, then I'd have to create another object, which is just a bit smaller to not have intersecting faces. That just doesn't seem like an elegant solution to me.